# Search between indexes

Tags: javascript

The following returns 2 indices.

I'd like to look between these 2 indices for the last line break.

```
var str = document.getElementById("output").value;
var indexFirst = str.indexOf(document.getElementById("prefix").value.toUpperCase());
var indexLast = str.lastIndexOf(document.getElementById("prefix").value.toUpperCase());
alert(indexFirst + " | " + indexLast);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but please put `document.getElementById("prefix").value.toUpperCase()` into its own variable. It's much harder to read as it is. Seems like a simple substring and a `lastIndexOf` would work for line breaks too, no?

Comment: Please specify your problem. What is your particular question?

Comment: Vladimir | lets say that the previous given example returns 20 and 88. I need to find the last line-break between these 2 indexes.

Comment: @Ethannn You can prefix the user name with a `@` to respond (and notify) to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go about and do something like this: [**Working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ta7ypjc7/)

```
var newStr = str.substring(indexFirst, indexLast); // get only the relevant part of the string
var pos = newStr.lastIndexOf("\n"); // find the last new line's index
alert(indexFirst + pos); // add the found index to the initial search index
```

[`.substring()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

[`.lastIndexOf()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Another option will be to chop off only the end of the string as so:

```
var newStr = str.substring(0, indexLast); // chop off the end
var pos = newStr.lastIndexOf("\n", indexStart); // search the last index starting from indexStart
alert(pos); // no need to add indexStart this way
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a few ways.

**Substring**

If you want to go down the route you have already started then you use:

`str.substring(indexFirst + 1, indexLast);`

***Working Example***

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdveyL

**Regular Expression** (Unnecessary after re-reading your answer)

Assuming | is "get text between this"

```
var re = /\|(.*?)\|/; 
var str = '|Hello|';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: Just noticed you wanted the last line break. Yotam's answer will be the right one for you.